# Java formatting decimals to 2 digits precision

Tags: java, format, double, precision, decimalformat

Right now I am doing this

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
//usage: df.format(someDouble);
```

But I don't know if this is the correct way to "round off" the display of a double to 2 decimal points. Will this work even if the number of digits to the left of the decimal point > 1?

Comment: did you test the code? what was the output?

Comment: I don't have a means to test the code at the moment

Comment: Then what is the problem with the code? are you asking if that's the way to do it?

Comment: Pro-tip: [Ideone](http://ideone.com/).  If you have access to SO, you have a means to test code (or at least trivial code like this).

Comment: @Ironcache Oh, sweet! I'll try that out, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

`DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");` means, that those decimal places are optional. You can see the difference when applying on `1.2` or `1.0`.

[image]

[--Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Comment: What if the number of digits to the left of the decimal point is greater than 1? As in I don't know why it's `#.00` and not something like `.00`

Comment: @KaliMa does not matter! whole numbers are not rounded :)

Comment: @KaliMa Why don't you try it out and see what happens?

Comment: @Andreas I would but I don't have a means to test my code at the moment

Comment: @KaliMa would you please clarify your last comment?

Comment: I can't install Java here / test it

Comment: Well this is weird. `double d1 = 0.5;DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); System.out.println(df.format(d1));` outputs `0.5` whereas if I exclude the leading `#` it removes the leading `0` and just outputs `.5`. Why isn't "zero showing up as absent"?

Comment: I told you. Use `"#.00"` `0` means - fill with zero if empty. # says skip if empty

Comment: @xenteros Please read what I said more closely (I am asking a slightly different question here): I am talking about the leading digits. If I use format `#.##` the leading 0 is included: `0.5`. If I use the format `.##` the leading 0 is excluded: `.5`. If `#` means "skip if empty", then why does it seem to be having the opposite effect here? When using that symbol, the 0 is not being skipped. It's only being skipped when I omit that symbol altogether.

Comment: It's because `.5` isn't a typical representation of a number. People use to write `0.5`

Comment: So the presence of the symbols mean different things depending on which side of the decimal point they're on? For instance `0.00` seems to mean "*at least* one digit will be shown, no matter what it is, on the left of the point, including 0, but *exactly* two digits will show to the right of the decimal point, no matter what"

Comment: @KaliMa exactly

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question about the rounding, the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)  tell it :

> Rounding
>
> DecimalFormat provides rounding modes defined in RoundingMode for formatting. By default, it uses RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN.

So this is up to you to set the `RoundingMode` that you want with [the setter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setRoundingMode(java.math.RoundingMode)).

```
public void setRoundingMode(RoundingMode roundingMode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work even if the number of digits to the left of the decimal point > 1?

Yes it will.